# How to match a regex with a fixed URL + variable slug

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to write the following regexes for `google analytics` usage and so far I was unable to.
Case 1. to match with all the URLs containing /cms/en/product/{variable slug}/ which only contains one slug after the /product/. I mean something like the following:

`/cms/en/product/firstslug/`

Case 2. to match with all the URLs containing /cms/en/product/{variable slug1}/{variable slug2}/ which only contains two slugs after the /product/. I mean something like the following:

`/cms/en/product/firstslug/secondslug/`

Really appreciate anyone's help in advance.

I have already tried basics like the following and it doesn't work:

`/cms/en/product/.*/$

^/cms/en/product/.*/$

^/cms/en/product/.*/$

/cms/en/product/([^/]+)/?$

^/cms/en/product/([^/]+)/?$`

Answer (score 0):

`^/cms/en/product/[^/]+/$` matches "/cms/en/product/firstslug/"

`^/cms/en/product/[^/]+/[^/]+/$` matches "/cms/en/product/firstslug/secondslug/"

`^/cms/en/product/[^/]+/([^/]+/)?$` matches both "/cms/en/product/firstslug/" and "/cms/en/product/firstslug/secondslug/"

**where**

`[^/]+` matches a single slug, i.e. one or more character(s) (`+`) which are not "/" (`[^/]`)
`([^/]+/)?` matches an optional slug, i.e. an optional (`?`) group (`()`) of one or more character(s) (`+`) which are not "/" (`[^/]`) followed by a single "/"

Anyway: I would suggest using [Content Grouping](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11523339?hl=en) on collection.